# Is my implementation of Strassen Slower than naive Matrix Multiplication?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, matrix-multiplication, strassen

So I've implemented Strassen'S Algorithm in C and even for large matrices it's not able to beat the classic ikj algorithm. I only use Matrices that er powers of 2, filled with doubles.
I read that for "large" n, Strassen's Algorithm beats the classic one, e.g. for n >= 1000. 
For me this is not the case. I don't use a cut-off point since, it's not part of the original algorithm. If i do, it's actually faster than the classic one, but without it's performing severely worse.
Is this the expected behaviour and the sources I found online about Strassen's Algorithm are actually using a cut off point?

I tried to optimize Strassen, by using only two matrices stored as one-dimensional array, passing them as arguments and actually not creating submatrices, if possible, but just passing the new size and a pointer two the cell so i don't allocate as much memory. But maybe for large Matrices this is actually bad since I'm accessing the whole matric and need to store it somewhere in main memory.

Here is a Github Link: https://github.com/AlexLoitzl/matmul
The Code is not properly documented yet...
And here is the Strassen Implementation:

```
void strassen_mult_base(int n, int x_row_length, const double X[], int y_row_length, const double Y[], int z_row_length, double Z[], int base, void (*inner_func)()) {

  if (n == 1){
    Z[0] = X[0] * Y[0];
    return;
  }

  const int k = n/2;
  //Split Matrices X and Y into 4 blocks without any memory allocation by using proper offset
  const double *A = X;
  const double *B = X + k;
  const double *C = X + k*x_row_length;
  const double *D = C + k;

  const double *E = Y;
  const double *F = Y + k;
  const double *G = Y + k*y_row_length;
  const double *H = G + k;

  //Allocate memory for temporary matrices P0 - P6 for our 7 Multiplications
  const int size = k*k*sizeof(double);
  double *P[7];
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    P[i] = (double *) malloc(size);
  }
  //Allocate memory for interim results of calculating P0 - P6
  double *S = (double *) malloc(size);
  double *R = (double *) malloc(size);

  // P0 = A*(F - H);
  sub(k, y_row_length, F, y_row_length, H, k, S);
  strassen_mult_base(k, x_row_length, A, k, S, k, P[0], base, inner_func);

  // P1 = (A + B)*H
  add(k, x_row_length, A, x_row_length, B, k, S);
  strassen_mult_base(k, k, S, y_row_length, H, k, P[1], base, inner_func);

  // P2 = (C + D)*E
  add(k, x_row_length, C, x_row_length, D, k, S);
  strassen_mult_base(k, k, S, y_row_length, E, k, P[2], base, inner_func);

  // P3 = D*(G - E);
  sub(k, y_row_length, G, y_row_length, E, k, S);
  strassen_mult_base(k, x_row_length, D, k, S, k, P[3], base, inner_func);

  // P4 = (A + D)*(E + H)
  add(k, x_row_length, A, x_row_length, D, k, S);
  add(k, y_row_length, E, y_row_length, H, k, R);
  strassen_mult_base(k, k, S, k, R, k, P[4], base, inner_func);

  // P5 = (B - D)*(G + H)
  sub(k, x_row_length, B, x_row_length, D, k, S);
  add(k, y_row_length, G, y_row_length, H, k, R);
  strassen_mult_base(k, k, S, k, R, k, P[5], base, inner_func);

  // P6 = (A - C)*(E + F)
  sub(k, x_row_length, A, x_row_length, C, k, S);
  add(k, y_row_length, E, y_row_length, F, k, R);
  strassen_mult_base(k, k, S, k, R, k, P[6], base, inner_func);

  // Z upper left = (P3 + P4) + (P5 - P1)
  add(k, k, P[4], k, P[3], k, S);
  sub(k, k, P[5], k, P[1], k, R);
  add(k, k, S, k, R, z_row_length, Z);

  // Z lower left = P2 + P3
  add(k, k, P[2], k, P[3], z_row_length, Z + k*z_row_length);

  // Z upper right = P0 + P1
  add(k, k, P[0], k, P[1], z_row_length, Z + k);

  // Z lower right = (P0 + P4) - (P2 + P6)
  add(k, k, P[0], k, P[4], k, S);
  add(k, k, P[2], k, P[6], k, R);
  sub(k, k, S, k, R, z_row_length, Z + k*(z_row_length + 1));

  free(R);  // deallocate temp matrices
  free(S);
  for (int i = 6; i >= 0; i--)
    free(P[i]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is expected.  For smaller matrices, Strassen is a loss.  And if you avoid the crossover, you'll have a lot of smaller matrices to deal with in a slow way.  But if you go to big enough matrices, Strassen becomes a win again.  (Though still loses to Strassen with crossover.)

Comment: @btilly Actually it doesn't. I think this might be due to the large contiguous array. Maybe it's easier for the ikj algorithm to load it into main memory partially. But I'm not sure.
So you are saying that the strassen algorithm without crossover should be faster?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I know that there are a few questions already. But the one you posted, for example, is allocating a lot of memory in every step and is therefore irrelevant to my question since i tried to optimize this already by using only one array. And I guess the essence of my question is, if it's supposed to be faster if implemented correctly for large matrices. I tried it with matrices of size 2^13*2^13 and it was still slower

Comment: @Alex Again expected.  Strassen is only a small win in the growth pattern.  If at size `n * n` it is a factor of `2` slower, you'd expect parity at around `32n * 32n`.  If it was a factor of 4 slower, you'd expect to need around `1000n * 1000n`.  Depending on "severely worse", you probably can't run big matrices enough to demonstrate the theoretical win.